# Google maps LatLng not a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I'm trying to create polygon markers on a Google map by converting a string containing lat/lng positions into an array. I'm running into the following error:

```
mc {message: "at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number", name: "InvalidValueError"
```

When i inspect the array in the browser console it looks fine (index[0]):

```
lat:"12.3394541791301"
lng:"55.59020913559151"
```

The string has the following structure:

```
'12.3394541791301,55.59020913559151, 12.3444451791347,55.5930451355941, 12.3808361791686,55.6099911356099,
```

So first i replace every second `comma` with `;`

When i use `split(";")` to create my array, which i when loop and push into a new array with the right keys:

```
s = s.replace(/([^,]+,[^,]+),/g,'$1;');
s = s.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var lat = s[i].split(',')[0];
        var lng = s[i].split(',')[1];
        // Push to array which is used by Google Maps
        denmarkLatLong.push({lat: lat, lng: lng})
}
```

Any suggestions to what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what a polygon marker is but I suspect you meant `marker`.

If you look at the latlng documentation the value for key `lat` and `lng` are supposed to be `Number` **not** `String`. So to fix your problem you can use the api `Number(...)` to cast the `string` coordinates into numbers.

**Example:**

```
s = s.replace(/([^,]+,[^,]+),/g,'$1;');
s = s.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var lat = s[i].split(',')[0];
        var lng = s[i].split(',')[1];
        // Push to array which is used by Google Maps
        denmarkLatLong.push({lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) })
}
```

**References:**

LatLng: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal

Answer (score 6):

Try to do this way:

These pluses will convert your string values of lat, lng to numeric. Or try `parseFloat()`

```
 denmarkLatLong.push({lat: +lat, lng: +lng})
```

**OR**

```
denmarkLatLong.push({lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)})
```

Problem that you have strings instead of numbers. Just convert, say if it helped.

```
lat:"12.3394541791301" // strings, convert to numbers
lng:"55.59020913559151"
```

Comment: loooolllll..........not enough to be correct and fistt..........pew pewpe  pw epwepw